# Why does creating a variable name for an exception raised in a Python function affect the reference count of an input variable to that function?

Tags: python, exception, garbage-collection, reference-counting

I've defined two simple Python functions that take a single argument, raise an exception, and handle the raised exception. One function uses a variable to refer to the exception before raising/handling, the other does not:

```
def refcount_unchanged(x):
    try:
        raise Exception()
    except:
        pass

def refcount_increases(x):
    e = Exception()
    try:
        raise e
    except:
        pass
```

One of the resulting functions increases pythons `refcount` for its input argument, the other does not:

```
import sys

a = []
print(sys.getrefcount(a))
for i in range(3):
    refcount_unchanged(a)
    print(sys.getrefcount(a))
# prints: 2, 2, 2, 2

b = []
print(sys.getrefcount(b))
for i in range(3):
    refcount_increases(b)
    print(sys.getrefcount(b))
# prints: 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Can anyone explain **why this happens**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a side effect of the "exception -> traceback -> stack frame -> exception" reference cycle from the `__traceback__` attribute on exception instances introduced in [PEP-344](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0344/) (Python 2.5), and resolved in cases like `refcount_unchanged` in [PEP-3110](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/) (Python 3.0).

In `refcount_increases`, the reference cycle can be observed by printing this:

```py
except:
    print(e.__traceback__.tb_frame.f_locals)  # {'x': [], 'e': Exception()}
```

which shows that `x` is also referenced in the frame's locals.

The reference cycle is resolved when the garbage collector runs, or if `gc.collect()` is called.

In `refcount_unchanged`, as per PEP-3110's [Semantic Changes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/#semantic-changes), Python 3 generates additional bytecode to delete the target, thus eliminating the reference cycle:

```py
def refcount_unchanged(x):
    try:
        raise Exception()
    except:
        pass
```

gets translated to something like:

```py
def refcount_unchanged(x):
    try:
        raise Exception()
    except Exception as e:
        try:
            pass
        finally:
            e = None
            del e
```

## Resolving the reference cycle in `refcount_increases`

While not necessary (since the garbage collector will do its job), you can do something similar in `refcount_increases` by manually deleting the variable reference:

```py
def refcount_increases(x):
    e = Exception()
    try:
        raise e
    except:
        pass
    finally:   # +
        del e  # +
```

Alternatively, you can overwrite the variable reference and let the implicit deletion work:

```py
def refcount_increases(x):
    e = Exception()
    try:
        raise e
    # except:               # -
    except Exception as e:  # +
        pass
```

## A little more about the reference cycle

The exception `e` and other local variables are actually referenced directly by `e.__traceback__.tb_frame`, presumably in C code.

This can be observed by printing this:

```py
print(sys.getrefcount(b))
print(gc.get_referrers(b)[0])  # <frame at ...>
```

Accessing `e.__traceback__.tb_frame.f_locals` creates a dictionary cached on the frame (another reference cycle) and thwarts the proactive resolutions above.

```py
print(sys.getrefcount(b))
print(gc.get_referrers(b)[0])  # {'x': [], 'e': Exception()}
```

However, this reference cycle will also be handled by the garbage collector.

Comment: This is a really excellent answer! Thank you for sharing your knowledge, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that writing out the question [helped us realize part of the answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). If we garbage-collect after each call to `refcount_increases`, the refcount no longer increases. Interesting! I don't think this is a complete answer to our question, but it's certainly suggestive. Any further information would be welcome.

```
import gc
c = []
print(sys.getrefcount(c))
for i in range(3):
    refcount_increases(c)
    gc.collect()
    print(sys.getrefcount(c))
# prints: 2, 2, 2, 2
```